# asp.net sizing the non-sizable

Tags: asp.net, charts, resize, size

I'm using the asp.net charting control, and liking it for the most part.  However, I would like my charts to size with the panels they are contained in.  I cannot set the width of the chart to 100%, I have to give them an exact size.  I don't want to stretch and distort the rendered chart image.
Does anyone have an example of how I might do this, or could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sizing requirement I would consider using flash or silverlight or javascript based charts like [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com) or other. I mean anything not generating static images. These are generated on the client so they can easily adopt to the dedicated space.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to stretch generated chart you can load it via ajax and pass size of current image container in an ajax request (e.g. www.site.com/generateCoolChart?height=200&width=300 ). But size of the container may be changed after the user change size of the browser so your chart may become bigger than your container.